# A three-part verb

Tags: riddle

> I am a verb; I come in three parts.
>
> The first recalls a pirate.
>
> The second reminds me of you!
>
> The last could be the opposite of out.
>
> -
>
> These parts, when combined but not whole,
>
> Result in what sounds like a question.
>
> Though don’t tell me teacher that it ended in a preposition
>
> -
>
> If you consider my case in a lower court,
>
> You can identify my parts in other ways, too:
>
> The first is a part of the last;
>
> The second is the inverse of the last
>
> The last is naturally the first plus more,
>
> And the inverse of the middle.
>
> -
>
> And now for my whole!
>
> I carry a connotation of swiftness, but that’s not always true.
>
> I can occur slowly, on a computer
>
> Or with a mouse, or a spider, or an ant – relativity is key.
>
> (And not the kind that Einstein discovered).
>
> -
>
> I am sister to some cousins of wordplay, diversion,
>
> A certain nearby star, and completion.
>
> If you haven’t found me yet, don’t run away!
>
> I’ve dropped myself somewhere around here –
>
> Perhaps you can spot me in that way!

What am I?

*Tip - the divisions of the lines have nothing to do with the answer; they just made the riddle look nicer.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Partial**

I think the answer is

> Run

I am a verb; I come in three parts.

> Three letters

The first recalls a pirate.

> R - Pirates in movies are associated with saying "Aarrr" which sounds like 'r'

The second reminds me of you!

> U sounds like you

The last could be the opposite of out.

> N sounds like 'in'

-

These parts, when combined but not whole,

Result in what sounds like a question.

> R U N sounds like 'are you in?'

Though don’t tell me teacher that it ended in a preposition

> 'in' is a preposition.

-

If you consider my case in a lower court,

> lower case, as suggested by GentlePurpleRain

You can identify my parts in other ways, too:

The first is a part of the last;

> The drawing of lowercase 'r' looks like a subset of 'n'

The second is the inverse of the first

> On a keyboard they are opposites?

The last is naturally the first plus more,

> Again referring to drawing the additional stroke on the 'r' to get 'n'.

And the inverse of the middle.

> 'n' is 'u' upside-down

-

And now for my whole!

I carry a connotation of swiftness, but that’s not always true.

> Run can mean to move one's legs in a swift manner

I can occur slowly, on a computer

> You can *run* a computer program which doesn't necessarily need to be quick

Or with a mouse, or a spider, or an ant – relativity is key.

> Different sized creatures will run at different speeds

(And not the kind that Einstein discovered).

-

I am sister to some cousins of wordplay, diversion,

A certain large star, and completion.

If you haven’t found me yet, don’t run away!

> Explicit use of the word **run**

I’ve dropped myself somewhere around here –

> In the previous sentence

Perhaps you can spot me in that way!

Comment: I think "lower court" means lowercase, and the clues refer to the shapes of the individual components.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Yes, great, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the verb is

> "run"

First section:

> r - recalls a pirate's "arrr"
>  u - reminds me of you, because its a homonym
>  n - another homonym, "in" could be the opposite of out

Second section:

> With all letters in lower case
>  To make the letter "r" you make most of the letter "n"
>
>  I think there's a typo here and it should read "the second is the
>  inverse of the last, as "u" is an upside down "n"

Third section:

> To run indicates quickness, but a computer could run slowly and
>  a mouse, a spider, and an ant would all run at different speeds

Fourth section:

> I take "sister to some cousins" to mean the word rhymes with words
>  that have these meanings
>
>  wordplay = pun
>  diversion = fun
>  large star = sun
>  completion = done
>
>  and the word "run" is hidden in this section